# Spinner items populated from SimpleCursorAdapter are not showing

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I have a spinner populated with items from SimpleCursorAdapter.
The problem is - they aren't visible in the spinner, but nevertheless I can pick one and it is visible as a selected item:

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp7Z1.png)

Here is the relevant code:

**Main2Activity.java**:

```
CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(Main2Activity.this,
        ContentProvider.createUri(Category.class, null), null, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor = cl.loadInBackground();
final SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Main2Activity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        cursor, new String[]{"name"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);

cursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spinner.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

**content_main.xml**:

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
```

**spinner_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Comment: for testing use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` in `SCA` constructor and `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` in call to `setDropDownViewResource()`

Comment: @pskink - The items are visible! How come? And how can I make it visible with my spinner layout (spinner_item.xml)?

Comment: well change `setDropDownViewResource` parameter and see what happens, if you see blank items again then compare those two xml files